# How to display transmission rate periodically in Mbps, the average for the last second?

Tags: java, networking, udp, bandwidth

I have tried looking for ways of how I could apply the formula **speed = data transferred / duration** in my Java program which sends packets (65000 bytes) through UDP protocol. The problem is that I don't seem to figure out how could I quantify the operations that are made to calculate, convert and sum up the data transferred in the last second or in 1 second. I have tried working with Timer, and TimerTrack and putting transferring the data in the run() function but then it throws IOException. I also considered delaying but that would just interrupt it for **X** **ms**.

Here is the code

public class UdpSnd  {

public UdpSnd() {  }

static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

```
  // first argument - destination address
  InetAddress target = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);

  // second argument destination port
  int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

  DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
  byte[] buf = new byte[65000];
  double sum = 0;
  double megabits = 0;

  while (true) {

     byte[] lineBytes = buf;

     DatagramPacket pkt = new DatagramPacket(lineBytes, lineBytes.length, target, port);
    // start
     megabits = lineBytes.length * 0.000008; // converting bytes to Megabits, also Bytes * 8 / 1000 * 1000
     sum = sum + megabits; // summing up the values to calculate the average 
     socket.send(pkt);
    // end --> should be the block of code that runs for 1 second to calculate average Mbps value for the last second
    
    // I want to output that periodically:
    // System.out.println(sum + " Mbps"); - not the correct way 

    sum = 0;

  }
```

}
}

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to start a periodic task that prints and calculates the sum. However, the calculated transfer rate is not too accurate because of the Java task handling if the output interval is chosen very short and the data rate is very high.